# This derivative is wrong. Isnt it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

so I have a function $y=\cos^2x$
We are supposed to find the derivative of it by first principles method.
Now what I get as my answer is $-2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.
but what my book has an answer, and a guide book, is: $-2x\sin^2(x)$.
So my question is basically this, isn't the answer provided by the book is wrong?

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \cos(x)^2 = -2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$, but $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \cos(x^2) = -2x \sin(x^2)$. It might be that the square is printed in the wrong position.

Comment: damn ..........@Ritz you are write its cos(x^2) .................... feel like such a fool.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It's wrong. Your answer is correct, assuming $y=\cos^{2}x=(\cos x)^{2}$. However, if $y=\cos(x^{2})$, then$$y'=-\sin(x^{2})\cdot(2x).$$

Comment: It doesn't matter, it can be written both ways

Comment: In the setting of this question, it does indeed matter that $\cos^2 x = (\cos x)^2$, because there is some suspicion that the OP has misread the notation of question in his book, or that the book has misused notation. @KSplitX

Answer (score 1):

if you have the function $$f(x)=\cos(x)^2$$ and the first derivative is given by $$y'=2\cos(x)(-\sin(x))$$